# How to abort ajax request on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form, on submit of that I am making an ajax request which is sometimes taking time to get the request, so what I am trying to do is whenever user refresh or clicks back button of the browser after `form submitting` i want to abort that ajax call

- What I am doing is

  ```
  $("#formId").submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var xhr = $.ajax({
        url : "Drilldown",
        method : "GET",
        success : function(data) {
           //  here doing ,my stuff    
        },
        complete : function() {
           $('.loader').hide();
           $('.overlay').hide();
        }
    });    
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       return "some message"; // here when user clicks on leave then want to abort like `xhr.abort`
    };    
  });
  ```
- whenever the user clicks on leave I want to abort my ajax request

How can I do that?

**I specifically want to do that when ever form submit and once form is submitted,i want to abort that function also `onbeforeunload` **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly xhr.abort() in "onbeforeunload" event handler method:

```
// Define xhr variable outside so all functions can have access to it
var xhr = null;

$("#formId").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    xhr = $.ajax({
        url: "Drilldown",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            //  here doing ,my stuff

        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.loader').hide();
            $('.overlay').hide();
        }
    });
});

window.onbeforeunload = onUnload;

function onUnload() {
    if(xhr) xhr.abort();
    return "some message";
};
```

Comment: i don't have any leave button, i just want to do that on page refresh button or back button of browser

Comment: So you can directly call that in "onbeforeunload" handler method.

Comment: hey i am doing like this `function onUnload() {
         if(xhr) xhr.abort();
        
     };` is this correct?

Comment: yes this is correct except that you should remove semicolon after function definition

Comment: ok i have done that,but its not aborting, my query in back end is still running?..` window.onbeforeunload = onUnload;
      function onUnload() {
          if(xhr) xhr.abort();
      }` this is how i am doing this

Comment: @dheeraj kumar if the request has already been sent to the server then the server will process the request even if we abort the request but the client will not wait for/handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

call below method to abort ajax call

```
xhr.abort()
```

Comment: i already new that, i want to call it when user clicks on leave?

Comment: You can call it on `window.onbeforeunload`

Comment: @Sayed in place of return?

Comment: yeah. No need of return. Just call the function

Comment: @Sayed i am doing like this `function onUnload() { if(xhr) xhr.abort(); };` is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this should do.